# Change key name in an array of objects based on value from first element array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6

I have raw json from file .csv like

```
[{
    "A": "CustomerCode",
    "B": "Country",
    "C": "CountryCode"
},
{
    "A": "C101",
    "B": "AUS",
    "C": "AUS01",
},
{
    "A": "C102",
    "B": "AUS",
    "C": "AUS02",
}]
```

How can I could remove first element of array and change key name of array object like that

```
[{
    "CustomerCode": "C101",
    "Country": "AUS",
    "CountryCode": "AUS01",
},
{
    "CustomerCode": "C102",
    "Country": "AUS",
    "CountryCode": "AUS02",
}]
```

Comment: Apart from the fact that you didn't show your code (I'm voting to close as *too broad*), this is probably a XY problem: you're dealing with the CSV header as if it was a common row. Changing that will fix the issue.

Comment: Tks for all comments. First of all, i got problem with convert excel csv to wrong format json. So this question not neccessary when i post this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `.map()` with `Object.entries()` and `Object.fromEntries()` to create new objects with keys from the first object in your array like so:

```js
const arr = [{A:"CustomerCode",B:"Country",C:"CountryCode"},{A:"C101",B:"AUS",C:"AUS01"},{A:"C102",B:"AUS",C:"AUS02"}];

const prop_map = arr.shift();
const res = arr.map(o => 
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(o).map(([k, v]) => [prop_map[k], v]))
);

console.log(res);
```

Above, `.shift()` gets the first object from the array as a mapping object to reference later. The `.map()` is then in charge of mapping (ie converting) each object to a *new* modified object. The new modified object is defined by what the internal function of `.map()` returns. In this can it takes the entries (a key-value pair array `[[key, value]]`) of objects and uses another `.map()` method. This `.map()` maps each key-value pair array to a new key-value pair array. However, the key now is defined by its associated value in the `prop_map` (the object we extracted at the beginning using `.shift()`). Now that we have an array of key-value pair arrays where each key is a value from the `prop_map`, we can use `Object.fromEntries()`, which converts this key-value pair array into an object. This new object is returned by the `.map()` being applied to the `arr`, which produces the final result.

Do note that Object.fromEntries() does have [limited browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries#Browser_compatibility), however, you can use a polyfill if need be.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the first item from the array then map over the array.

```js
let data = [{
    "A": "CustomerCode",
    "B": "Country",
    "C": "CountryCode"
},
{
    "A": "C101",
    "B": "AUS",
    "C": "AUS01",
},
{
    "A": "C102",
    "B": "AUS",
    "C": "AUS02",
}];

// Remove first item in array
data.shift();

let newData = data.map(({A, B, C}) => ({
    CustomerCode: A,
    Country: B,
    CountryCode: C
}));

console.log(newData);
```